# Let $A$ be a bounded open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Give an example where $\int_{\bar{A}} f$ exists but $\int_A f$ does not.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, measure-theory

Integration in the Riemann sense.

Let $A$ be a bounded open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$; let $f: \mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$ be a bounded continuous function. Give an example where $\int_{\bar{A}} f$ exists but $\int_A f$ does not.

I cannot think of any such example. I would greatly appreciate it if anyone can provide me with some insight.

Comment: In which sense are you defining integration, Lebesgue or Riemann? In the Lebesgue sense this result is nonsensical, since $f 1_A$ will necessarily also be integrable if $f$ is.

Comment: Sorry should've made it clear, I mean Riemann.

Comment: @Ian: this might be silly, but is it obvious that $1_A$ is measurable if $1_{\overline{A}}$ is?

Comment: @Giovanni $A$ is open and $\overline{A}$ is closed, so the indicator functions are definitely measurable.

Comment: @takecare How do you define Riemann integration on an open set? (All notions of Riemann integration that I understand depend on compactness.)

Comment: @Ian: missed that assumption, to be fair I have only read your comment :) thanks for the quick reply

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this statement makes sense as formulated. In particular, if $f$ is integrable on $\overline{A}$, then its set of discontinuity points has measure zero. The restriction of $f$ to $A$ will not add any discontinuity points (because it can be given by the composition of $f$ with the inclusion map, and the inclusion map is continuous). So the set of discontinuity points of the restriction will also have measure zero, so $f$ will be integrable on $A$ as well (if that notion even makes sense in the Riemann setting).

A reformulation (assuming we've somehow sensibly defined Riemann integration on an open set) is as follows. Let $C$ be a fat Cantor set, let $A=[0,1] \setminus C$, and then consider $f=1_A$. Then $f$ is actually continuous on $A$, because it is constant there. But no matter what, $f$ cannot be Riemann integrable on $\overline{A}$, because its set of discontinuity points is $C$ which has positive measure.

In view of the Lebesgue criterion for Riemann integrability, pretty much any example will be more or less of this type, unless somehow your definition of integration on an open set does not respect the Lebesgue criterion. Indeed it seems the entire discussion hinges on this definition, which is not at all obvious to me.

Comment: I don't really understand your example. $f$ is supposed to be continuous on $\mathbb R^n$, not only on $A$. Beside $f$ is supposed to be integrable on $\bar A$.

Comment: @user251257 I agree, I had to change some of the original hypotheses somewhat because as formulated they do not make sense. In particular, if $f$ is integrable on $\overline{A}$, then no discontinuities are introduced by restricting to $A$, so by the Lebesgue criterion, $f$ is also integrable on $A$ (whatever that even means in the Riemann case).

Comment: @user251257 Edited my comment accordingly.

Comment: @user251257 I edited my answer as well, is it clearer?

Comment: @user251257 Er, what? $A$ is a bounded open set. $f=1$ will be integrable on both $\overline{A}$ and $A$. There is no way to satisfy the OP's condition by having the integrals blow up.

Comment: @user251257 If $f$ is integrable on $\overline{A}$, then unless there are some discontinuities introduced by restricting to $A$ (which there can't be for topological reasons), or unless there is some strange criterion behind the scenes for integration on an open set, then $f$ will be integrable on $A$ as well. In particular $f=1$ will be integrable on both $A$ and $\overline{A}$.

Comment: Ah. I misunderstood the second paragraph. Sorry

Comment: @ takecare  If  $f$ is trivial function(i.e. $f=0$ )can you choice  such $A$? -the answer is no.  You must  exactly  indicate  the  form  of the $f$.

Comment: @Ian The Riemann integral $\int_M f$ is defined as $\int_Q f\cdot \chi_M$, where $Q$ is a rectangle containing $M$. Thus multiplication with $\chi_A$ can introduce discontinuities on a set of positive measure while multiplication with $\chi_{\overline{A}}$ introduces only discontinuities on a null set. Taking your $A = [0,1]\setminus C$, and $f \equiv 1$, we clearly have $f\cdot \chi_{\overline{A}} = \chi_{[0,1]}$, which is Riemann integrable, but $f\cdot \chi_A = \chi_A$ isn't.