# Improper/extended multiple integral and change of variables

Tags: multivariable-calculus, improper-integrals, lebesgue-measure, multiple-integral, change-of-variable

I have a problem with improper integral in my book. You need to know the following information.

1) I am using this definition of improper/extended integrals over open sets: 
Let $A$ be an open set in $R^n$; let $f : A \rightarrow R$ be a continuous
function. If $f$ is non-negative on $A$, we define the $(extended) \ integral \ of \ f \ over \ A$, denoted $\int_A f$, to be the supremum of the numbers $\int_D f$, as $D$ ranges over all compact rectifiable subsets of $A$, provided this supremum exists. In this case, we say that $f \ is \ integrable \ over \ A$ (in the extended sense).

2) I am also using this $change \ of \ variables$ version:
Let $g: A \rightarrow B$ be a diffeomorphism of open sets in $R^n$. Let $f : B \rightarrow R$ be a continuous function. Then $f$ is integrable over $B$ if and only if the function
$(fog)|detDg|$ is integrable over $A$; in this case, 
                               $$\int_B f=\int_A (fog)|detDg|$$

I am trying to understand this example from my book: 
Suppose we wish to integrate the function $x^2y^2$ over the open set $W$={$(x,y)$ | $x^2+y^2<a^2$}. Here the use of polar coordinates is a bit more tricky. The polar coordinate transformation $g$ does not in this case define a diffeomorphism of an open set in the $(r,θ)$ plane with $W$. However, $g$ does define a diffeomorphism of the open set $U = (0, α)$ x $(0, 2π)$ with the open set $V$ = {$(x, y)$ | $x^2 + y^2 < α^2$ and $x < 0$ if $y = 0$} of $R^2$.
The set $V$ consists of $W$ with the non-negative $x$-axis
deleted. Because the non-negative $x$-axis has $measure \ 0$ (and even $content \ 0$) , $\int_W x^2y^2$ exists and
$\int_W x^2y^2=\int_V x^2y^2$.
The latter can be expressed as an integral over $U$, by use of the polar coordinate transformation.

MY QUESTION IS why is this claim true?: Let $f:W \rightarrow R$ be continuous (and possibly unbounded) and $W$ is an open subset of $R^n$ such that it is the union of the open set $V$ and the set with measure $0$ $E$. If the extended integral $\int_V f$ exists, then the extended integral $\int_W f$ also exists and
$$\int_W f=\int_V f$$.

Is it possible to prove this at least in the case that $E$ has $content \ 0$?
Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theorem 15.6 in *Analysis on Manifolds* by Munkres states

> For an open set $A \subset{R}^n$ there exists a sequence $\{O_j\}$ of
>   open sets such that $O_j \subset O_{j+1}$
>   and $A = \cup_{j=1}^\infty O_j$. The extended integral $\int_A f$
>   exists if and only if the sequence $\int_{O_j} |f|$ is bounded, in which case we
>   have
>   $$\lim_{j \to \infty} \int_{O_j} f = \int_A f$$

I will add that each $O_j$ can be chosen as the interior of a compact rectifiable set $\bar{O}_j$ and, since, $f$ is continuous and bounded on $\bar{O}_j$ the integrals $\int_{\bar{O}_j} f  = \int_{O_j} f$ exist properly.  (The existence of $\int_{O_j} f$ over the interior and equality to $\int_{\bar{O}_j} f$ follows from Theorem 13.6 in Munkres.)

I think I have found a way to prove this statement for the case that $E$ has $content \ 0$. For this problem we are given that $W = V \cup E$ where $W$ and $V$ are open and $E$ is of measure $0$. We can assume that $V \cap E = \emptyset$ (since this seems to be the right way to state this theorem), so that $V=W-E=W \cap E^c$. We are also given that $f$ is continuous on $W$ and the extended integral $\int_V f$ exists.

Take a sequence $O_1 \subset O_2 \subset  \ldots$ of open sets such that $W = \cup_{j=1}^\infty O_j$. Since $O_j \subset W$, then $O_j=O_j \cap W$. Thus the sets $\hat{O}_j = O_j \cap E^c=(O_j \cap W) \cap E^c=O_j \cap (W \cap E^c)=O_j \cap V$ are also open and and nested with union $V = \cup_{j=1}^\infty \hat{O}_j$.

We know that if $A$ has content $0$ then it is $rectifiable$ (it is bounded and its boundary has measure $0$) and it has measure $0$. Thus it can be proven (by Theorem 11.3) that $\int_A f$ exists and equals $0$.

Now since $O_j \cap E \subset E$ and $E$ has content $0$, then $O_j \cap E$ has content $0$. It follows that $\int_{O_j \cap E} |f|=0$. Then by Corollary 13.4

$$\int_{O_j} |f| = \int_{\hat{O_j}} |f| + \int_{O_j \cap E} |f| = \int_{\hat{O_j}} |f|$$.

Thus the sequence $\int_{O_j} |f|$ is bounded and the extended integral $\int_W f$ exists.  Furthermore, as shown for $|f|$,

$$\int_{O_j} f  = \int_{\hat{O_j}} f,$$

and, it follows that,

$$\int_W f = \lim_{j \to \infty}\int_{O_j} f  = \lim_{j \to \infty}\int_{\hat{O_j}} f = \int_V f$$

Comment: Excuse me. Cound you explain some of your statements to me? Why do the 3 specific integrals you use exist and why does the limite of $C_j \cap E^c$ equal $\int_V f$? Also how do I know that the closure of $C_j \cap E^c$ is a compact rectifiable subset of V so that I can say it is bounded?

Comment: Ok. Thank you for your help. I am physicist self studying this material after having taken a non-rigorous multivariable calculus course, so I don't have the mathematical backgrand to fill these gaps myself. I really appreciate the help!

Comment: I was thinking if by excluding E from $C_j$ it is possible to create such "holes" in $C_j$ that its boundary get big enough to no longer be of measure $0$.

Comment: How do I know that $E^c$ is open?

Comment: Ok. I have read carefully your answer. In Munkres' example $E$={ $(x,0) \in R^2| 0 \le x < α$ }. So if I choose $x=(0,α) \in E^c$ then each $neighborhood \ of \ x$ intersects $E$, so $E^c$ isn't open. Also by Munkres $theorems \ 11.3$ and $13.4$, we have to assume the existance of $\int_{O_j \cap E} f$.

Comment: I have made some changes in my post. Please take a look at it if you insist on this problem. Thank you for your persistance. Your help is invaluable.

Comment: Sorry for troubling you. I just can't even find the existance of this statement in any book. So if we are to prove something I have to be completely sure. I think I proved that the $\hat{O_j}$ are open without the assumption that $E^c$ is open. I edited my thoughts inside your answer. The only doupt I have now is about the existance of the integrals $\int_{O_j \cap E} f$. If $E$ has $content \ 0$ then so does $O_j \cap E$ and is therefore rectifiable with volume $0$. Thus $\int_{O_j \cap E} f$ exists and it equals $0$. Can we, however, prove its existance when $E$ has $measure \ 0$?

Comment: I think I see why you have this concern.  There can be a set $A$ of measure $0$ such that for $f$ continuous, $\int_{\bar{A}} f$ exists but $\int_A f$ does not -- and it is even possible for $A$ to be open -- as I show [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2830162/148510.) For this problem the set $E$ is a line segment embedded in the plane so it has content $0$ and this is not an issue.

Comment: To review we set out to prove that removing a set of measure zero preserves the extended integral.  With great pain we reduce this to proving that removing a set of measure zero preserves the proper integral $\int_{\hat{O}_j}f  = \int_{O_j} f$.  All because Munkres makes a comment in an example that some integral  is zero as it is taken over a set of measure $0$.  Perhaps he meant to say content $0$.

Comment: Yes exactly. This book is supposed to be too easy by many but I have found many missteps in it like the proof of theorem 20.1, which if it was complete, it wound take 3 pages to write it. Anyway, what do you propose? Should we accept the existance of this statement only for $E$ with $content \ 0$ or should we try to prove the more general case of $E$ with $measure \ 0$?

Comment: I would end this here satisfied with the fact that content zero is enough to explain how Munkres came to his conclusion.  It is now clear that the Riemann integral over a measure zero subset may not exist since it may not be rectifiable and all of this breaks down purely because of a technicality.  To delve deeper I would ask another question.

Comment: Yes but as a physicist I am more interested in a rigorous approach of multivariable calculus than mesure theory which I think has little to do with physics despite its relation to probability. Do you happen to be a member in facebook. I would like to know people how care more about helping people than gaining "reputation" and "privileges". In a previous question of mine somebody wanted to me to "accept" his answer despite the fact that I hadn't fully understand why his statements were correct. But I accepted it so he woundn't flag my post.

Comment: @ΒασίληςΒούλγαρης: I have no Facebook account. You can always ping me here.  Yes -- I looked at your other question and see how the user "reminded" you to accept the answer. Seems quite pathetic for a user with over 100,000 points to do that.  The point system plays a role in making this site work, however a handful of users seem to be obsessed, I have seen behavior that suggest such users are unclear that "reputation" extends far beyond a point total -- quality of answer, quality of question, etc -- not to mention glad-handing and pandering.

Comment: Also you are never obliged to accept an answer.  You would not have been flagged -- and if you were in any way threatened or intimidated (as a new user), that should be flagged. If you were not satisfied, you should have not accepted the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much dor your time and effort. I appreciate your 2-day long struggle deeply. I will add the explanation of $E$ being of $content \ 0$ and will accept your answer. Cound you explain to me how I can find specific members here and simply talk to them instead of posting a question and hoping to find them?

Comment: Wait a second. To break the integrals we have to know that the "partial" integrals exists in the ordinary sense. How do we know the integrals $\int_{O_j \cap E^c} f$ actually exist in the ordinary sense?

Comment: Take a rectangle Q containing $O_j$ and show directly with Riemann sums that $\int_Q f \chi_{O_j \cap E^c}$ exists. Since $E$ is rectifiable with content zero you can construct a partition where the rectangles  that cover $O_j \cap E$ have arbitrarily small total volume.

Comment: Take a rectangle $Q$ such that $O_j \subset Q \subset W$. Cover $O_j \cap E$ with rectangles of total volume less that $\epsilon/4M$ where $M = \sup_{x \in Q} f$. Using endpoints extend to a partition of $Q$.  There exists a partition $P$ such that $\sum_{R_j \in P} (M_j-m_j) vol(R_j) < \epsilon/2$, etc.

Comment: Ok. I am going to try and show it. Thank you again!