# There exist a compact not rectificable set

Tags: integration, measure-theory, riemann-integration

What shown below is a reference from "Analysis on manifolds" by James R. Munkres

[image]

So Munkres gives a counterexample of open and bounded set that is not rectificable and then as exercise he asks to find a closed and bounded set that is not rectificable. Unfortunately I can't find this such set so I ask to find it. Then I ask if there exist some condictions for which I can claim that a compact set is rectificable. So could someone help me, please?

Comment: Munkres gives an open, non-rectifiable set, call it $S$, such that $S \subset [a,b]$ for some interval $[a,b]$ of $\mathbb{R}$. If you take the set $T = [a-1,b+1] - S$, this set is closed, bounded, and the boundary of $T$ contains the boundary of $S$, so $T$ is not rectifiable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [fat Cantor set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Volterra%E2%80%93Cantor_set) is closed, bounded and of non-zero measure.  It has empty interior so every point is a boundary point and every boundary point is in the set (since it is closed).

Comment: @RLL Okay, I know Cantor set. In particular let be $F_0:=[0,1]$ and so for any $n\ge 1$ let be $F_n:=F_{n-1}\setminus\bigcup_{k=0}^{n-1}(\frac{1+3^k}{3^n},\frac{2+3^k}{3^n})$ so that we define $C:=\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb{N}}F_n$ and we call $C$ cantor set. So when I sudied topology I proved that $C$ is compact but I don't prove that $\overset{°}S=\varnothing$ and that $\partial C$ (using Munkres definition) has measure zero: so could you explain better, please?

Comment: Then can you say if there exist some conditions for which I can claim that a compact set is rectifiable?

Comment: First -- your middle-thirds Cantor set has measure zero. The fat Cantor set (see the link) has a non-zero measure and uses a different choice of excluded intervals.

Comment: @RLL Okay, give me some time to understand your counterexample: now here it is too late so tomorrow I will reflect about your answer. Anyway what can you say about my last question, that is can you say if there exist some conditions for which I can claim that a compact set is rectifiable?

Comment: I don't think there is an easier example of a compact non-rectifiable set.  As you can see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2830093/148510) the fat Cantor set comes up again in answering a question from Munkres.  As it appears you are working your way through this book, it would probably be of further benefit to understand this example.